# SQL Server openrowset from csv on shared drive works from server not from desktop or app

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I set up a stored procedure to import data from a csv file on a network drive.  I trouble shoot all the previous errors and setting that are the usual requirements to make this work. I'll put that T/S info below with the boiled down code. I am at the point where this works perfectly when I run it from SSMS 2016, which is running on the windows 2012r2 server, which is running the sql server 2016, and I am logged in via Remote desktop as my network admin id.  But does not work when I run it from SSMS 2016, which is running on windows 10 desktop, and I am logged it as the same admin id.

It also failed when I call the sp from the app on my desktop, which will be the actual place I want to call it from.

Code:

```
select *  
from openrowset('MSDASQL'
,'Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}'
,'select * from \\servername\public\Utilities\SWUMOps\BackEnd\saws\accts.csv')
```

Error from ssms on desktop:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver] '\servername\public\Utilities\SWUMOps\BackEnd\saws' is not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.".
>
> Msg 7320, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
> Cannot execute the query "select * from \servername\public\Utilities\SWUMOps\BackEnd\saws\accts.csv" against OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)".

.............

- I've set the temp folder in the profile of the service id to everyone and domain users to modify
- I have the 64bit driver loaded on the 64bit sql server
- I have set 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
- I verified the SQL Server service ID is in the Global group that has permissions to the folders and file on the remote share.

All the research I've done keep pointing me back the these steps above.
I also saw something about forcing tcp/ip instead of named pipes, but named pipes wasn't enabled,  which it is now.

It seems to be related to how the permissions are used differently from when you run the tsql from on or off server , so I was hoping that would ring a bell for one of you fine folks.

Thanks

edit:
I also tested the sql svr service id by logging on to my desktop with it and opening the file on the unc path with no problems.

Comment: Could you map \\servername to a Shared Drive (i.e. have it mapped to like Y: for instance)

Comment: Gave it a shot, no luck.  Thanks